# expect send interpreting text in variable as switch

Tags: tcl, expect

I am a complete novice when it comes to expect / Tcl.  I am trying to use expect to test my custom mail configuration but it seems like it is interpreting the contents of my line buffer as having additional flags when I want it to be treated as literal text.  The error I get is caused by the MIME boundary.  Any help would be appreciated (I have found similar questions but without answers).

```
bad flag "--------------040802090700050105080302": must be -i, -h, -s, -null, -0, -raw, -break, or --
```

```
spawn telnet $server 25
expect "Connected"
expect "220 "
send "HELO <domain>\n"
expect "250 "
send "MAIL FROM: <sender>\n"
expect "250 "
send "RCPT TO: <recipient>\n"
expect "250 "
sleep 2
send "DATA\n"
expect "354" 
sleep 2
set fh [open mailtest.txt]   
while {[gets $fh read_line] != -1} {
        send $read_line      # This explodes when the line starts with --
        send "\n";
}
close $fh
send ".\n"
sleep 2   
send "QUIT\n"
```

Example partial input (MIME delimiter causes explosion):

```
... header ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary=------------040802090700050105080302

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------040802090700050105080302   <-- bomb
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

... rest of MIME body ...
```

Comment: And nevermind.  I of course find the answer as soon as I posted the question: send -- "string"

Comment: If you've got the answer, do a self-answer. It's allowed and encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after searching around, I found the answer in a couple of different places.  Send just needed a (--) parameter to signify that there would be no additional flags and that all remaining text is literal text:

```
while {[gets $fh read_line] != -1} {
        send -- $read_line
        send "\n";
}
```

[Exploring Expect](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/exploring-expect/9781565920903/ch12s09.html)